# How can I remove the Apple Logo and brightening effect at the Login Screen in Mac OS X 10.7 Lion?

Tags: osx-lion

How can I remove the Apple Logo at the Login Screen in Mac OS X 10.7 Lion?

Also, how can I remove the brightening effect upon the wallpaper? I want to change it to my own, but the brightening effect renders it less than perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logo is located at

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LoginUIKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Log‌​inUICore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/apple.png
```

appleLinen.png is also there; I forget which one. Replace them with images w/o anything in them to rid the screen of the logo.

The wallpaper is located at

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/Resources/NSTexturedFullScreenBackgroundColor.png
```

It's a repeating image, so dimensions ought to be the same as your screen and at 72 dpi.

As to the brightening effect, as far as I know, no-one has been able to get rid of it (I personally spent a while searching the System files for something like it); so it may be drawn programmatically. Take a look at [this Ask Different Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18451/how-can-i-customize-the-lion-login-screen-both-the-background-and-the-vignette).

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use Loginox to change/remove the Apple logo from Logon Screen

http://www.addictivetips.com/mac-os/change-mac-os-x-10-7-lion-login-screen-with-loginox/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have FileVault enabled? Because that can cause some problems when customizing the login logo. Here's a guide someone created on how to [change the logo when you have FileVault 2 enabled](http://zephauniah.com/2013/02/11/how-to-change-the-apple-logo-on-your-macs-login-screen-with-filevault-2-enabled/).